# ORA-01861 in WebService but the SP is working

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a SP that contain 3 input parameters and 4 outputs. inputs are NUMBER, the outputs one is a VARCHAR(descResponse) and the others are NUMBER.

In java, when I log the response:
`logger.info("Out["+res.getCodResponse()+"]["+res.getDescResponse()+"]");`
the print is:
`Out[-1861][ORA-01861: literal does not match format string]`

The map between java attributes with the SP parameters are the same type (number : Integer/Double, varchar: String).

the problem is when i use sql developer with the same parameters the response is ok. So i don't know if my WS is not working or the SP.

Comment: You're doing an implicit date conversion somewhere intour SP, and the NLS settings are different. Can't be more specific as you haven't shown that code. You'll need to go through it and find the date reference(s) that are wrong. You could change your settings in SQL Developer to break it, then you might see the line number in the error stack. Good luck.

Comment: Please share your SP Signature, Java declaration variables, also, If it is possible sample parameter values when you get this error.

Comment: thanks @Alex Poole, changing the NLS settings i could detect and fix the wrong date reference, i didn't know the NLS settings, thanks for that =).

Answer (score 0):

I hava distinct NLS settings on my sql devoloper than my DB so I change the NLS settings on my sql devoloper and i could detect the wrong date reference and fix it.